# Why is TCPDF putting question marks on me in various places?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to edit a pdf from jelix.
And I don't understand why I get question marks on different places of my pdf... For example :

[image]

with :

```
    <tr>
        <th align="center" rowspan = "2">Repas prévus</th>
        <th align="center">jeudi 15 soir</th>
        <th align="center">vendredi 16 midi</th>
        <th align="center">vendredi 16 soir‬</th>
        <th align="center">samedi 17 midi‬</th>
        <th align="center">samedi 17 soir</th>
        <th align="center">dimanche 18 midi‬</th>
        <th align="center">dimanche 18 soir</th>
    </tr>
```

Can you help me understand what I did wrong ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Some of the characters might be UTF-8 encoded, this example might help https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_008/

Comment: Most likely the issue is that your strings contain characters for which the font you are using do not contain a symbol. So first check the character encoding you are using, that it matches between what you actually have in the PDF and what you assume you have, then check what characters those positions actually have, best is to use a "hexeditor" for that...

Comment: Maybe give [this a coat of looking at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: The fonts you are using likely don't have the accented characters in them. On the TCPdf pages you'll find a package that does support UTF-8 (and do look at the link RigssFolly mentioned).